# Installation of the surprisal package in Pycharm fails due to conflicting dependencies: What solutions exist?

Tags: python, package, conflict

I am trying to install a package to my Pycharm Project.

When I try to install the package 'surprisal', it fails with the following ouput:

```
ERROR: Cannot install surprisal==0.1.0, surprisal==0.1.0.post1, surprisal==0.1.1 and surprisal==0.1.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    surprisal 0.1.2 depends on torch<2.0.0 and >=1.12.0
    surprisal 0.1.1 depends on torch<2.0.0 and >=1.12.0
    surprisal 0.1.0.post1 depends on torch<2.0.0 and >=1.12.0
```

I am a kind of newbie and I absolutely don't know how to handle that issue. I did some researches with Google and Stackoverflow, but I didn't find any help.

Is there anyone who could help me, please?